# Laravel filesystem and ftp

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, filesystems

im having a hard time with the filesystem of Laravel. Im trying to generate, save and transfer a xml-file in a controller.

everything but the ftp-transfer works. I suspect it is because i cant get the right path of the new xml-file in the sendFilToNCS($fileName) function. Im getting this error:

> ErrorException ftp_put(/storage/1584533245.xml): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

Hope to get som help from the laravel-experts. Good day.

```
class ExportController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function index($id){

        $foromtale = Foromtale::find($id);
        $data = new NCSNote($foromtale);

        $xml = View::make('xmlTemplate')->with('view', $data);

        $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

        return $this->writeXml($xmlDoc);
    }

    public function writeXml($content){

        $fileName = time().".xml";
        //$content->saveXML($fileName);
        Storage::put($fileName, $content);
        Storage::move($fileName, 'storage/'.$fileName);

        return $this->sendFilToNCS($fileName);           

    }

    private function sendFilToNCS($fileName)
    {
        $content = Storage::disk('local')->url($fileName);
        $ftp_server = "ftp.host.dk";
        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
        $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "username", "xXxxXX");

        // upload file
        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $fileName, $content, FTP_ASCII))
          {
          // close connection
          ftp_close($ftp_conn);

          return true;
        }
        // close connection
        ftp_close($ftp_conn);
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Storage facade without any changes will put your files in `storage/app`. I do not see the point in moving the files afterwards. Imaging you would put your files in `storage/app/xml` for easier overview. This could be obtained like this.

```
$fileName = '/xml/' . $fileName;
Storage::put($fileName, $content);
```

When you want to get the file path, the storage facade has a helper for that. Which will return the absolute path, you will need for `ftp_put()`.

```
$path = Storage::path($fileName)
```

Seems like you are using `ftp_put()` wrong. The third parameter is a path to the file, use the newly defined `$path` property.

```
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $fileName, $path, FTP_ASCII)
```

There is a lot of aspects in this code, but this seems like the most obvious errors, I'm not certain it will get you the whole way, but should get you to the next step in the process.